# Fedora Add/remove software problem

Tags: installation, fedora

Whenever I try to run Add/remove software from menu, it gives me this error:

> PackageKit Error: Running graphical
>   applications as privileged user should
>   be avoided for security reasons.
>   Therefor this application will close.

I m currently logged in as root.

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Log in as a non root user. If you want to install software as root use `yum` from the command line, although it's still recommended to use a non root user and run `yum` via `sudo` to avoid other possible mishaps in the command line.